# File.getFilename() in Arduino?

Tags: c++, file, arduino, filenames, arduino-ide

**UPDATE:**
There's no getfilename(), but there's name() function!

---

I'm trying to make a simple program to store all filenames in a String array and then show them in the LCD.
Code:

```
String* list(File root, int len) {
    if (!root.isDirectory()) return NULL;
    String files[50];
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        File f = root.openNextFile();
        if (i < 50) files[i] = f.getFilename();
        f.close();
        i++;
    }
    len = i;
    root.close();
    return files;
}
```

Code to display in LCD:

```
void displayToLCD(String* files, int len) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.home();
    lcd.print("Files on SD:");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(files[i]);
        delay(1000);
    }
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.home();
}
```

But the problem is that the class File doesn't have the 'getFilename()' function. Is there any way to get the filename?
Please help.

Best regards,
Mateiaru

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered that that on arduino.cc at File section, at openNextFile example, they use File.name()! So there's no getFilename().

Mateiaru

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at my [MP3 FilePlayer.ino](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_file_player_8ino_source.html) example. It accomplishes what you are attempting, but just to the serial port.

Additionally it won't run out of memory, as it does not store the file names into an array or memory. Rather [displays them](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_file_player_8ino_source.html#l00373) and lets the user [select the number](http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_file_player_8ino_source.html#l00167). This can also be readily adapted to an up/down arrow menu, for an LCD.

Note that I am using SdFat. It has more functions and attributes that are not made public in standard SD. along with the file.getFilename() .

Comment: No, I really need to save them in memory. I am building a file manager for Arduino which uses LCD, not Serial port (it doesn't even contain "Serial.begin(9600)").

Comment: Keep in mind that the Arduino's ATmega328 has only 2K of RAM (8K for the mega2560). And I believe the LCD library uses a large chunk and so does the SD library, leaving only a few hundred of bytes left. Where my example was not to use the serial port but to demonstrate how to deploy the idea of playing files from an indexed list and that such a list of filenames be displayed separately, as not to store any list in memory. This idea same idea has been used to then up/down menu on smaller displays such as LCD's.

Comment: I have arduino uno r3, and no ram problem yes.